# How to append already created html form into table using javascript dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a dropdown which has values from 1 to 6(need to add more).
In that html i have created a blank table and a form .

what i am tryin to do is ..when i select value 1 from dropdown , i want form of id 1 should be appended to table

and when i select value 2 form with the value of 2 should be appended not any other

Till now what is happening when i select the drop form added to html table but it is not visible

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
 <table border ="1" align='center'>
  <tr>

     <td>
     <select id="colors" onchange="changedesc()">
     <option value="1">Desc1</option>
     <option value="2">Desc2</option>
     <option value="3" >Desc3</option>
     <option value="4">Desc4</option>
     <option value="5">Desc5</option>
     <option value="6" >Desc6</option>
     </select>
     </td>

  </tr>
  </table>

  <table id ="addform">

  <!-- to be inserted here the div-->
  </table>

  <form id=1 style="visibility: hidden;">
    <input type="text">
    <textarea>abc</textarea>
   </form>
  <form id=2 style="visibility: hidden;">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="checkbo">
  </form>
  

  </div>

  <script>
   function changedesc(){
   var eID = document.getElementById("colors");
   var colorVal = eID.options[eID.selectedIndex].value
   if (colorVal=="1"){
   var frm = document.getElementById(1);
   frm.removeAttribute("style");
   var ff = document.getElementById("addform")
   ff.appendChild(frm);
   
   }
   if (colorVal=="2"){
   var frm = document.getElementById(2);
   frm.removeAttribute("style");
   var ff = document.getElementById("addform")
   ff.appendChild(frm);
   //how to remove previuos one
   }
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few point to mention here:

- in your snippet there is a closing `</div>` tag, this would lead to invalid HTML.
- you have a table with one cell that holds a select button, I suggest that you use `<div>` since table is made to be used for displaying data that meant to be viewed as a table.
- you have another table with no `<tr>`, `<td>`, and appending the form tag to id, not having `<tr>`, `<td>` tags will be invalid HTML and cause the HTML to not render.
- the hidden forms use `id` attribute of `1` and `2` although its parsed and recongniszed by the browser I suggest that you use a more meaningful ids.
- one last thing as a suggestion is to use the `display`/`visibility`/`opacity`  attributes to toggle show/hide the forms instead of appending them here.

  Here is a snippet with a working HTML from your snippet:

```js
function changedesc(){
 var eID = document.getElementById("colors");
 var colorVal = eID.options[eID.selectedIndex].value
 if (colorVal=="1"){
  var frm = document.getElementById(1).cloneNode(true);
  console.log(frm);
  frm.id="new-form1"
  frm.removeAttribute("style");
  var ff = document.getElementById("form-td");
  ff.innerHTML = "";
  ff.appendChild(frm);

 }
 if (colorVal=="2"){
  var frm = document.getElementById(2).cloneNode(true);
  frm.id="new-form2"
  frm.removeAttribute("style");
  var ff = document.getElementById("form-td")
  ff.innerHTML = "";
  ff.appendChild(frm);
  //how to remove previuos one
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
 <table border ="1" align='center'>
  <tr>

     <td>
     <select id="colors" onchange="changedesc()">
     <option value="1">Desc1</option>
     <option value="2">Desc2</option>
     <option value="3" >Desc3</option>
     <option value="4">Desc4</option>
     <option value="5">Desc5</option>
     <option value="6" >Desc6</option>
     </select>
     </td>

  </tr>
  </table>

  <table id ="addform">
    <tr>
      <td id="form-td"></td>
    </tr>
  <!-- to be inserted here the div-->
  </table>

  <form id=1 style="visibility: hidden;">
    <input type="text">
    <textarea>abc</textarea>
   </form>
  <form id=2 style="visibility: hidden;">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="checkbo">
  </form>
  <script>
   
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```